# Jekyll: Include record in site.records but do not render html page

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll setup that looks like this:

```
_config.yml
_records
  a.html
  b.html
  c.html
...
```

I want to create a home page that links to each record. However, I want to render `a.html` and `b.html` to `/records/`, but I don't want to render `c.html` to `/records/`, as that HTML will be provided to my server from a different process altogether.

I tried setting the following in `_config.yml`:

```
exclude:
  _records/c.html
```

But this also removes `c.html` from `site.records`, which is not what I want. The best solution I have right now is to prevent my deploy script from deploying `_site/records/c.html`, but I'd much rather prevent `_site/records/c.html` from being generated in the first place.

Is it possible to include `c.html` in `site.records` to create the links on the home page but not render `/records/c.html`? Any help others can offer with this question would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did this. Inside `_records/c.html`, set in the front matter:

```
permalink: '_'
route: /records/c.html
```

That will make it so that we render the page's html content to `_site/_.html`, a route that won't ever get visited.

Then in `index.html` to create the link to the `route` attribute of this page, use:

```
{% for record in site.records %}
  {% if record.route %}
    {% assign url = record.route %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign url = record.url %}
  {% endif %}
  <a href='{{ url }}'>{{ record.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```